Z-order of forms in Delphi
I have a very simple application with two forms, both with Formstatus := fsNormal.
The project autocreates both forms.
On Form1, I have a button with
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show
end;

When you click on Button1, Form2 appears in front of Form1, which is okay.
But when you click on any place on Form1, Form2 stays in front of Form1?!
Form1 receives focus, as its caption becomes bold, but I expect Form1 to appear in front of Form2!
What am I missing?
Delphi 11 Community Edition
When creating two forms, Form2 and Form3, and I can switch between both of them, but not with Form1
Application

It is related to the MainFormOnTaskBar setting controlling the Aero support: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MainFormOnTaskBar
"Note that it affects the Z-order of your MainForm in case your application depends on this."

That solved my problem. Danke schön, Uwe!
